# Gio.SimpleAction not emiting change-state signal

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, gio

I am trying to create a `Gio.SimpleAction` and connecting to its `change-state` signal, for taking an specific action when the state is changed, but I have failed to come up with a working code.

Here is an example of what I have tried (and expected to work), without success:

```
from gi.repository import Gio, GLib

call_count = 0
def _state_changed(action, state):
    action.set_state(state)
    global call_count
    call_count += 1
    print(state)

a = Gio.SimpleAction.new_stateful('foo', None, GLib.Variant.new_boolean(False))
a.connect('change-state', _state_changed)

print a.get_state().get_boolean()
a.set_state(GLib.Variant.new_boolean(True))
print a.get_state().get_boolean()
print call_count
```

The output of running this code is:

```
False
True
0
```

As we can see, the state is indeed changed, but no change-state was emitted!

Is there something wrong with this code sample? How do I properly detect a state change in a `Gio.SimpleAction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set_state()` method effects a state change. The `change-state` signal is only emitted in response to a state change request, from `Gio.Action.change_state()`.

I believe the signal is mainly intended to allow subclasses of `Gio.SimpleAction` to inject code into the handling of state change requests.

Comment: Yes. Thankyou. Changing a.set_state(GLib.Variant.new_boolean(True)) to a.change_state(...) fixes the problem.